# Need help downloading bucket from Google Cloud

Tags: python, download, cloud, bucket, gsutil

My computer crashed and I need to download everything I stored on the Google Cloud. I am not a computer tech and I can't seem to find a way to download whole buckets from Google Cloud.

I have tried to follow the instructions given in the Google help docs. I have downloaded and installed Python and I downloaded gsutil and followed the instructions to put it in my c:\ drive (I can see it there). When I go to the command prompt and type cd \gsutil the next prompt says "c:\gsutil>" but I'm not sure what to do with that.

When I type "gsutil config" it says "file 'c:\gsutil\gsutil.py", line 2 SyntaxError: encoding problem utf8".

When I type "python gsutil" (which the instructions said would give me a list of commands) it says "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" even though I did the full installation process for Python.

Someone suggested a more user-friendly program called Cloudberry Explorer which I downloaded and installed, but the list of sources I can set up does not include Google Cloud.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your research is correct, I think that the most efficient way of doing this is with gsutil. Troubleshooting this will be tricky, you'll have to have patience...especially since this is a windows.

First you need to confirm your python. Do the following command.

```
which python
```

if correctly installed, it should tell you the version number.

Check gsutil.py; it may help to open a python session and see if you can import the necessary modules. A session will start by just typing python. The modules is the usually at the beginning of the script... something like import "module" or from "blahh" import "blahh"

Once installed, this will do the trick:
[Download files and folders from Google Storage bucket to a local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640637/download-files-and-folders-from-google-storage-bucket-to-a-local-folder)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is that gsutil tools works only with python version 2.7 or lower for windows.
Once you have the correct python version, Please follow following steps if you are a windows user :

1. open commend prompt and switch to your gsutil directory using:
   -- cd\
   -- cd gsutil
2. Once you are in the gsutil directory execute following command:
   python gsutil config -b
3. This will open a link a browser requesting you access to your google account. Please make sure you are logged into google from the account you want to access cloud storage and grant access
4. Once done, this will give you a KEY (authorization code). Copy that key and paste it back into your command prompt. Hit enter and now this will ask you a PROJECT-ID.
5. Now Navigate to your cloud console and provide the PROJECT-ID.
6. If Successful, this will create a .boto file in c:\users.
7. Now you are ready to access your private buckets from cloud console. For this, user following command: C:\python27>python  c:\gsutil\gsutil cp -r gs://your_bucked_id/path_to_file path_to_save_files